# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable respect constraints

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi I am using swift ui render a list of items in a `VStack` inside a `ScrollView` , where some of the are already designed as UIKit `UIView`.

wrapping the uiviews inside a UIViewRepresentable, should do the trick, but, the items bounds are zero at runtime.

the expected behaviure is that the uiview should fill the vstack horizontally, and the constrints of the uiview should determine the hight.